# How to change the boolean value of a global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

```
start=True
def funcA():
   if(start):
       #doSomething
    else:
       start=False
```

this leads 'starts' to  an unresolved reference 
Is there a way to change 'start' to False inside funcA ?

Comment: Just put `global start` in the function

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them.